# No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'

Tags: android

I have created a project with following settings for Target :

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

But following error persists at values-v11 and values-v14:

ERROR : No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: try this `parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`

Comment: @Raghunandan tried ... Cleaned the project.. But Same error.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html. check this. check the note in the link. your min sdk is 8. `Theme.Holo` family, available in API level 11 and higher

Comment: @Raghunandan tried , but no success... same error

Comment: you din't read the docs full pls check the docs. if you don't do it right you get same error

Comment: Problem was with Build Target not minSdkVersion ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title appears to have been added in API Level 13. Make sure your build target is set to 13, not just 11.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion=...
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

Answer (score 29):

Assuming you're using Eclipse, you need to right-click your project in the Package Explorer, select **Properties**, select **Android**, and set **Project Build Target** to API level 14 or higher.  Or equivalently, set `target=android-14` or higher in your project's `project.properties` file, but note that this file is autogenerated by Eclipse, so manually editing it is not recommended.

Comment: Clean and build after the above, if necessary.

Comment: I had to do this with an older project that wasn't updated using Android Studio and the Gradle build system. There was an external library (Fabric-Twitter) that required `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light`. Setting the value `target=android-21` within the  `project.properties`  file resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

First there is problem in the `parent` attribute, you have to use `parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"`

Second, Since Holo Theme was introduced in API level 14... so you have to change your `android:minSdkVersion="8"` to `android:minSdkVersion="11"`, On newer versions it will automatically use Holo theme. You can further read about Holo Theme at

- [On Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html)
- [on Developers.Android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

However if you want to support previous versions of Android for Holo Themes. You can use [Holoeverywhere library](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere).

Comment: Problem was with Build Target not minSdkVersion ... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can Click Properties of this project and click Android,chose Target Name byond you aim project.