# Type error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.

Tags: android, eclipse

When I import my Android Project in eclipse, I have a following error.

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.  styles.xml  /INU_app_new/res/values-v11 line 7  Android AAPT Problem

And this is the error source code.

**style.xml**

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"> 
 //That is the error line.
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you duplicate an existing question, but nevermnid.

Here you would find how to fix your issue:

[No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18631643/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-androidtheme-holo-light)

[No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27121847/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-androidtheme-holo-light-darkacti)

If you're usung Gradle in Eclipse you can also try to set the values in the `build.gradle` like this (updated for API 21):

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 21
  buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21 //Depends on the min version you would like to support
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: I have found the answer. The API number is error. But still thanks very much your suggestion.